# Events in Office js api for Addins

Tags: office365, office-js

I have tried

Office.context.document.settings.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.SettingsChanged,()=>{console.log("event changed")},(res)=>{console.log("event completed")});

in order to monitor the change in the property such as file rename. However no of this work. since I can not target a specific change.

I would like to know if there is an event listener or addHandlerAsync for onbeforeprint, download and sharedocument?

Answer (score 0):

The supported event types are listed here: [Office.EventType](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/office/office.eventtype?view=excel-js-preview). It looks like none of the events that you are interested in are supported. But its an interesting idea. Please suggest it at [Office Developer Suggestion Box](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).